# javax.xml.validation.Schema not reading server file in JBoss EAP 5.1 correctly

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jboss, xsd

I have the following Java code running on a RESTEasy web service, to get a schema file to validate xml against (note: The project folder is called "MyWebService"):

```
String classDir = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();    
String myWebServiceDir = classDir.substring(0, classDir.lastIndexOf("MyWebService"));       

String instanceXSDPath = myWebServiceDir + SCHEMAS_FOLDER + xsdFile;
System.out.println("Streamsource file location: " + instanceXSDPath);
File file = new File(instanceXSDPath);

//StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(file);
// Note: Using StreamSource or File seems to make no difference to the issue
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(file);
```

When I run the above code on my local machine, everything works great.  However, when I run the above code on my development server, I get the following error:

> 2013-11-20 12:47:48,275 INFO  [STDOUT] (ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-4)
>   Streamsource file location:
>   file:/Y:/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/DEVELOPER_DEPLOY/Schemas/Extensions/1/instance.xsd
>   2013-11-20 12:47:48,275 ERROR
>   [com.mywebservice.dao.validate]
>   (ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-4) Could not parse the given object for schema
>   validation:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed
>   to read schema document
>   'file:/Y:/jboss/jboss-as/bin/file:/Y:/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/DEVELOPER_DEPLOY/Schemas/Extensions/1/instance.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not .    at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)

I don't understand why on the server EAP logs the above code is trying to read in instance.xsd from a path that looks like this:

```
'file:/Y:/jboss/jboss-as/bin/file:/Y:/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/DEVELOPER_DEPLOY/Schemas/Extensions/1/instance.xsd'
```

... because on my localhost EAP logs it is reading instance.xsd from a location that looks like this:

> 'location:
>   /C:/Users/chen/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1382499548190/deploy/Schemas/Extensions/1/instance.xsd'

Does anyone have any ideas as to why?  Why is the print message saying 'file' on the server, but 'location' on my locahost in the server logs of each respectively?  Perhaps that has something to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use  StreamSource and set the System Id of the StreamSource to it's original path like so:

```
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(file);
System.out.println("Stream source system id: " + streamSource.getSystemId());
streamSource.setSystemId(xsltPath);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(streamSource);  // change for each artefact type
```

This worked, to prevent the mashing of two 'file:' locations, since it hardwired the System Id to be just one.  I have no idea why the server was mixing two 'file:' locations into the System Id, but who cares, problem solved!